# How to avoid empty search using jquery in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a search function in wordpress and there are two search boxes. One is a simple textbox in searchform.php which has a jquery validation with the following code:

```
function title_validate() {
var e = 0;
return e = jQuery(".search-box").val().length, 3 > e ? (alert("Search text should not be blank or contain at least 3 letters!"), !1) : void 0
}
```

The other is inside the search.php which is for detailed search including filters such as categories. The validation code is as follows:

```
function title_inner_validate() {
var e1 = 0;
return e1 = jQuery(".search-fun-name").val().length, 3 > e1 ? (alert("Search text should not be blank or contain at least 3 letters!"), !1) : void 0
}
```

The second validation is not working. I tried the `console.log` but no luck. How can I fix this?

Or can anyone help me in validating the textbox (with class name) to avoid empty search.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion i think u should use the **jquery validate library**

```
  $( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    search-fun-name : {
      required: true,
      maxlength: 4
    }
  }
})
```

don't forget to import the library

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<scriptsrc="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js">
</script>
```